# how to rephrase this code to get past clippy::manual_let_else

Tags: rust, rust-clippy

after some upgrade of msrv I get this (In a project I dont own, just doing the msrv upgrade, so removing the 'pedantic' is not OK)

```
error: this could be rewritten as `let...else`
   --> asyncgit/src/sync/config.rs:99:2
    |
99  | /     let entry = match entry_res {
100 | |         Ok(ent) => ent,
101 | |         Err(_) => return Ok(None),
102 | |     };
    | |______^ help: consider writing: `let Ok(ent) = entry_res else { return Ok(None) };`
```

on this code

```
let entry_res = cfg.get_entry(key);

let entry = match entry_res {
    Ok(ent) => ent,
    Err(_) => return Ok(None),
 };
```

`get_entry` returns a `Result<T,...>`

The suggested fix is not valid code - unless I missed something obvious

Edit. When I say not valid code, I mean it won't compile, I am sure the syntax is correct and that it's my fault for not being able to follow what it's trying to do. But it's for sure a clippy bug

EDIT2 : apparently a known bug https://github.com/rust-lang/rust-clippy/issues/10171

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The suggested fix is not valid code - unless I missed something obvious

The suggested fix seems to have a pretty simple error (which you should report): it should be

```rust
let Ok(entry) = entry_res else { return Ok(None) };
```

Otherwise it creates the wrong top-level binding (`ent` rather than `entry`).

Aside from that, the suggested code has been valid code [since 1.65.0, released November 2022](https://blog.rust-lang.org/2022/11/03/Rust-1.65.0.html#let-else-statements) (and longer than that on nightly).

Though it is possible clippy does not properly take MSRV in account, I've no idea.

Comment: Ty, I was very frustrated and could not work out what it was suggesting (the fact that there was a variable called 'ent' in the original was confusing

Comment: FYI - alreday reported as a clippy bug